# FactoryBot refuses to build factory with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot

Can't find the reason why FactoryBot refuses to build factory with associations to same model with has_and_belongs_to_many relation.

Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
#...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :refs,
    class_name: "Product",
     join_table: :refs,
    foreign_key: :from_id,
    association_foreign_key: :to_id,
    dependent: :destroy
  after_destroy :destroy_inverse_refs
#...
end
```

Ref model:

```
class Ref < ActiveRecord::Base
#...
  belongs_to :from, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'from_id'
  has_one :to, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'id', primary_key: 'to_id'
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :ref do
    association :from, factory: :product
    association :to, factory: :product
  end
end
```

Can't find the reason why this factory builds :from association with id and :to association without it:

```
ref = FactoryBot.build(:ref)

puts ref.inspect
#<Ref id: nil, from_id: 8965, to_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

puts ref.from.inspect
#<Product id: 8965, category_id: 12167, name_en: "Product name 1">

puts ref.to.inspect
#<Product id: nil, category_id: 12168, name_en: "Product name 2">
```

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reading https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations I have only one idea why.

Imagin this

```
P1 --from-> REF --to-> P2
```

REF belongs_to P1, so REF.from_id is assumed to be required. So most probably `FactoryBot` playing safe and guesses that it's better to create `from` object and save it in DB, and that's why the ID is already there.

On the other hand `has_one :to` the P2 creation in the DB can be safely deferred until ref is saved.

Maybe in your case `FactoryBot`'s guesses are incorrect, and you might want to play with `strategy:` option for association.

If you want both IDs available, try `strategy: :create` but not sure if it'll  render `build(:ref)` essentially behave like `create(:ref)`

Comment: Just changed 
    has_one :to, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'id', primary_key: 'to_id'
in Ref model to
    belongs_to :to, class_name: 'Product', foreign_key: 'to_id'
and Factory started generating all fine.

Thanx for your tip!